# Quadruple "const" in function definition

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer

I am wondering about how C++ uses its const keyword.

I have the following function definition. Which alone looks quite insane, but works just fine.

```
const int const * const Get(){ return new int(1); } const
```

I am aware of what each placement of the const means, this question isn't about the meaning of the placement of the const keyword.

I am quite confused by the use of the const keywords, because you can duplicate them.

```
const int const const * const Get(){ return new int(1); } const

// or even

const const int const const * const const Get(){ return new int(1); } const const

// or even yet

const const const int const const const * const const const Get(){ return new int(1); } const const const
```

Why does the language allow you to do this?

EDIT:
This code can be compiled in Visual Studio 2013, Visual C++ compiler. I am not sure about the actual name of the compiler.

EDIT2:
So the answer is that this is against the standard. The code only compiles wihout using `/Za` option.

I am voting to close the question.

Comment: Ah ah wtf ? you right looks insane, I'm curious to learn the meaning of that.

Comment: Re "Why does the language allow you to do this?", it doesn't.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/627d4ef5325d292a `Error: duplicate 'const'`

Comment: **−1** Not real code.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I dont really know why would you say that. How is it not real? It is valid c++ code, tested by compiling.

Comment: @Python- compiling proves nothing about code being valid according to the standard. Did you remember to tell the compiler to not use any extensions? Are you sure the compiler conforms to the standard?

Comment: @Python-: re "tested by compiling", please tell us which compiler, and if possible the exact invocation. i tend to *not believe you* though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a real question. The alleged facts in the question are not true.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It compiles in Visual Studio 2013. I read that it uses its own compiler.

Comment: @Python- did you remember to use the [/Za](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx) option when you compiled? Without it your result is meaningless. If the code does work with that option, then it seems that we've found out that VS2013 doesn't conform to the standard.

Comment: MSVS2103 gives the following warning: `warning C4114: same type qualifier used more than once`. And with `/Za` it actually generates the error: `error C2289: same type qualifier used more than once`

Comment: @Python- Re " It compiles in Visual Studio 2013", no, none of the code lines presented compile with Visual Studio 2013. However, that compiler only chokes on the syntax errors, and just produces *warnings* for the multiple `const`s. So possibly there are two issues: (1) you have not upped the warning level when you tested, and (2) the code you compiled did not have the final `const` that you *added* when you posted the code here.

Answer (score 10):

Explicitly repeating `const` in the same type specifier sequence is disallowed in the standard.

[dcl.type]/2 (emphasis mine)

> As a general rule, at most one type-specifier is allowed in the complete decl-specifier-seq of a declaration or
>   in a type-specifier-seq or trailing-type-specifier-seq.
>
> ...
>
> — **const can be combined with any type specifier except itself.**

One might think that this is allowed from the following quote (found by @davidhigh):

[dcl.type.cv]/1

> There are two cv-qualifiers, const and volatile. Each cv-qualifier shall appear at most once in a cv-qualifier-seq. If a cv-qualifier appears in a decl-specifier-seq, the init-declarator-list of the declaration shall not be empty. [ Note: 3.9.3 and 8.3.5 describe how cv-qualifiers affect object and function types. — end note ] **Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored**. [ Note: For example, these could be introduced by typedefs. — end note ]

However, this rule is to allow `const` duplications which arise through substitution in templates or `typedef`s, not those explicitly typed by the programmer.

Taking one of your examples:

```
const const int const const * const const Get(){ return new int(1); } const const
```

The first four `const`s all apply to the `int`, breaking the rule posted above.

The next two `const`s apply to the pointer and are invalid by the same rule.

The final two `const`s are not even part of the declaration for `Get`. They will be applied to whatever the parser finds next, becoming invalid by either the same rules as above, or by other C++ syntax rules.

VS2013 may compile such code using language extensions, but this is not standard behaviour. [gcc 5.1.0](http://goo.gl/mMVV6g) and [clang 3.5.1](http://goo.gl/9cuNhh) will both refuse to compile your code and both provide a reasonable diagnostic.

Comment: You could be more clear on what "this" is. There are multiple issues.

Comment: sounds reasonable, but it seems like a clash to me. Is there something like an inheritance-rule to be used (loosely: [dcl.type.cv] inherits this behaviour from [dcl.type])?

Comment: I don't think there's a clash. [dcl.type] says you can't repeat `const`. [dcl.type.cv] says redundant `const`s are ignored, then qualifies this by noting that these could be introduced using `typedef`s. If you repeat `const`s, you are breaking the first rule and your program is ill formed. If you repeat them using `typedef`s, your program is fine because the second rule excepts this.

Comment: still, another thought: this needs to be interpreted with a given priority of the standard quotes in mind. You could also interpret it as "first remove redundancies", then "disallow multiple consts" (which would render the latter rule itself redundant). The quote obviously shows how it is meant -- but from the view of a pedantic this interpretation is at least possible.

Comment: As you say yourself, this would render the latter rule redundant, so why would it be in the standard in the first place if it's an impossible situation? I think that alone would invalidate taking any other stance.

Comment: Sure. We can stop here. The C++ standard is not an axiomatic system. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Re

> **”** Why does the language allow you to do this?"

it doesn't. The code presented is **not real code**. E.g.

```
const int const * const Get(){ return new int(1); } const
```

(the first example) will not compile with any standard-conforming compiler, for two reasons:

- The multiple `const`s at the start (for the `int`) are not permitted.
- The `const` at the end is a syntax error.

Standardeese for the first point: C++11 §7.1.6/2,

> **”** `const` can be combined with any type specifier except itself.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit/delete when I got it: where exactly does the quote in my answer looses its applicability for a case as in the OP?

Comment: @davidhigh: for the standardeese see TartanLama's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/30798876/464581). still you should **check reality** before posting. and when someone points this out to you, you should do that immediately and not ask others to do your quality assurance for you. sorry if this sounds rough. i got a little upset.

Comment: no problem, doesn't sound rude, but also doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because the standard says so. Here is an excerpt from [dcl.type.cv] which states exactly this (emphasis mine) :

> There are two cv-qualifiers, const and volatile. Each cv-qualifier shall appear at most once in a cv-qualifier-seq.
>   If a cv-qualifier appears in a decl-specifier-seq, the init-declarator-list of the declaration shall
>   not be empty. [ Note: 3.9.3 and 8.3.5 describe how cv-qualifiers affect object and function types. — end note ]
>   **Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored.** [ Note: For example, these could be introduced by typedefs. — end
>   note ]

This makes sense in templates, for example. If the template parameter is deduced as `const`, it can easily happen that another const is added somewehere.

---

**EDIT**: as noted several times and redundantly, my above answer is misleading in that it does not qualify here. It is opposed by the rule in [dcl.type] which explicitly disallows explicitly typed `const` qualifiers (see the fine comment by @TartanLlama in his answer).

---

**EDIT 2**: the application of the rule everyone seems to agree on states: first redundant `const`s are disallowed, and if they still should somewhere occur they are ignored.

This, however, requires a priority of the standard quotes.

Without, one could also think of an order like: first remove redundant `const`s, and only then apply the rule that multiple `const`s are not allowed (which, of course, would render the latter rule itself redundant).

In this case, obviously, the quote shows how it is meant to be interpreted. But, being pedantic, *it does not have to be interpreted like this* -- unless there is some form of priority in the standard quotes.

Comment: This is actually wrong. The standard prohibits this

Comment: @BЈовић: yes, we had that. Resolve the seeming clash.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: you can have another look.

Answer (score 0):

This function declaration (and others)

```
const int const * const Get(){ return new int(1); } const;
```

will not compile because according to the C++ Standard (7.1.6 Type specifiers, #2)

> — const can be combined with any type specifier **except itself**.

and (7.1.6.1 The cv-qualifiers)

> 1 There are two cv-qualifiers, const and volatile. Each cv-qualifier
>   **shall appear at most once** in a cvqualifier- seq.

In this declaration for example qualifier const is combined with itself

```
const int const * const Get(){ return new int(1); } const;
^^^^^     ^^^^^
```

Moreover the last qualifier is placed in the wrong place.:)

```
const int const * const Get(){ return new int(1); } const;
                                                    ^^^^^
```

At leats there should be

```
const int const * const Get() const { return new int(1); };
                              ^^^^^
```

Or in this declaration (if to place the cv-qualifier sequence correctly) at least cv-qualifier sequence has more than one const qualifier

```
const const int const const * const const Get() const const { return new int(1); };
                                                ^^^^^ ^^^^^
```

Opposite to C++ in C you may combine several qualifiers in a declaration. The redundant qualifiers are simply ignored. For example

```
const long const long const int const x = 10;
```

that is equivalent to

```
const long long int x = 10;
```

However in C++ this declaration will not compile.

Comment: Re "because", note that there's also a syntax error, namely the final `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Two separate issues.

1. By default MSVC issues a warning ([C4114](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9db2t0x.aspx)) for repeated qualifiers rather than an error. The standard permits this since all that's required is a diagnostic message, and a warning satisfies this requirement.
2. The final `const`s compile only when they are actually part of a subsequent declaration. For instance:

   ```
   const const int const const * const const Get(){ return new int(1); } const const

   int main() {}
   ```

   This is actually

   ```
   const const int const const * const const Get(){ return new int(1); } 

   const const int main() {}
   ```

   which is "OK" modulo the repeated qualifiers part.

Comment: Re the hypothesis here, another hypothesis is that the OP tested with a `#define const` (as nothing). For example. ;-) For other readers: yes one can use `main` as a member function name.